# What's the best way to set up Active Directory for one user with a Domino Mailbox on the backend?

Tags: active-directory, smtp, exchange-server, lotus-domino, email

Scenario:

A Domino Server with a Mail-in Database, as part of an application, resides in an Exchange environment.

We want to create an email address in Active Directory but tell it to route mail to the mail-in database on the Domino Server.  Setting up the Domino Mail-in Database is the easy part.  (There's inbound mail only, btw).

The application is able to send outbound email via an SMTP gateway within the environment.

Question:
How does one configure AD for a back-end Domino mailbox?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.

Comment: Even a high-level answer will do.